# Issue data-binding in conditional rendering (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Anyone have an idea what my issue may be here?

I have two buttons changing a data value (`categoryName`). I know this is working as intended.

Then I’m trying to use conditional rendering to render the `<template>` if `business.category` is equal to `categoryName`

I know that conditional formatting works if I manually type in a new value for categoryName. But something isn’t working with the buttons updating the value.

**Here's the code**

```html
<div>
    <button v-on:click="categoryFilter = 'cheap'">cheap</button>
    <button v-on:click="categoryFilter = 'expensive'">expensive</button>
</div>

<template v-for="business in cardData" v-if="business.category == '{{ categoryFilter }}'">

    <!-- HTML Content goes here -->

</template>
```

**And the JSON**

```js
            data: {
                categoryFilter: "",
                cardData: [
                    {
                    category: "expensive"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

Instead of:

```html
v-if="business.category == '{{ categoryFilter }}'"
```

I removed the curly brackets and single quotes:

```html
v-if="business.category == categoryFilter"
```